# Using dplyr to label and count gaps between values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
    df<-structure(list(Name = c("sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", 
                            "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", 
                            "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", "sub1", 
                            "sub1", "sub1", "sub2", "sub2", "sub2", "sub2", "sub2", "sub2"
), StimulusName = c("Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", 
                    "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", 
                    "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", 
                    "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha12", "Alpha12", "Alpha12", "Alpha12", 
                    "Alpha12", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", "Alpha11", 
                    "Alpha11"), FixationSeq = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
                                                3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                NA, NA, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                     "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), StimulusName = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "collector")), FixationSeq = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

In the column `FixationSeq` there are unique numbers (in my example 2 and 3 for `Name` = `sub1` and `StimulusName`= `Alpha11`). Between these numbers there are segments filled with `NA`. There is also a segment after 3 filled with `NA`.

I would like to be able create a new column `SaccadeCount` and add an incrementing numerical label to every instance of an `NA` **segment** (as a whole, i.e. potentially multiple rows) to the relevant rows in `SaccadeCount`.

Additionally, I'd like to have another column called `SaccadeDuration` and total the number of rows where unique segments of `NA` appear. So in the example `df` the rows corresponding to the `NA` segment between 2 and 3 would be populated with '3' since that is the total number of rows between 2 and 3.

I would like to accomplish this using dplyr and group the operation by the columns `Name` and `StimulusName`.

An output might look something like this:

```
    Name    StimulusName    FixationSeq SaccadeCount    SaccadeDuration
   sub1     Alpha11             2       
   sub1     Alpha11             2       
   sub1     Alpha11             2       
   sub1     Alpha11             2       
   sub1     Alpha11             NA            1              3
   sub1     Alpha11             NA            1              3
   sub1     Alpha11             NA            1              3
   sub1     Alpha11             3       
   sub1     Alpha11             3       
   sub1     Alpha11             3       
   sub1     Alpha11             3       
   sub1     Alpha11             3       
   sub1     Alpha11             3       
   sub1     Alpha11             NA            2              5
   sub1     Alpha11             NA            2              5
   sub1     Alpha11             NA            2              5
   sub1     Alpha11             NA            2              5
   sub1     Alpha11             NA            2              5
   sub1     Alpha12             1       
   sub1     Alpha12             NA            1              2      
   sub1     Alpha12             NA            1              2
   sub1     Alpha12             2
   sub1     Alpha12             NA            2              1  
   sub2     Alpha11             NA            1              4
   sub2     Alpha11             NA            1              4
   sub2     Alpha11             NA            1              4
   sub2     Alpha11             NA            1              4
   sub2     Alpha11             2                  
   sub2     Alpha11             2
```

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Hi! It's not clear to me how `SaccadeCount` is created, can you elaborate more? Also in your example `FixationSeq` is different from the output you showed.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had updated the df. Have done now. The df is now consistent with the text. The example output at the end is slightly different to the dataframe I include to demonstrate the various group_by levels.

Comment: Hi @Andre Elrico. I'm finding your approach very aggressive. I explained that the *text* is consistent with the dataframe. I also explained that the *output* example differs slightly to highlight how a larger dataset will look. I'm trying to keep my df as small as possible to work with. Also, why are you going through my question history? That is not relevant to this question and is frankly creepy.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Andre Elrico.

Comment: @Docconcoct Please note that it's _much_ easier for people to try out their code if toy data and desired result correspond. Regarding "_keep my df as small as possible_": your desired output actually has _fewer_ rows (but importantly: sufficient complexity) - why not just base 'df' on that, it's already there! ;) Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Henrik, I'll see if I can update the df to make it more complex and still be able to squeeze within the character limit. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: The data is already there - just `dput` the first three columns of the desired output, which is already in your post. Your toy data will then be _smaller_ not bigger ;) But again, it is slightly more complex, in terms of having combinations of both the two grouping variables represented. Cheers

Comment: Hi @Henrik, I think that the data and output match now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Name, StimulusName) %>%
  mutate(x = is.na(FixationSeq),
         count = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 0L) & x) * x,
         dur = NA_integer_) %>%
  group_by(Name, StimulusName, count) %>%
  mutate(dur = replace(dur, as.logical(count), n()))
```

---

Corresponding (more succint) `data.table` version:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ , count := ({
  x <- is.na(FixationSeq)
  .(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 0L) & x) * x)}), by = .(Name, StimulusName)]

df[as.logical(count), dur := .N, by = .(Name, StimulusName, count)]
```

> ```
>     Name StimulusName FixationSeq count dur
> 1:  sub1      Alpha11           2     0  NA
> 2:  sub1      Alpha11           2     0  NA
> 3:  sub1      Alpha11           2     0  NA
> 4:  sub1      Alpha11           2     0  NA
> 5:  sub1      Alpha11          NA     1   4
> 6:  sub1      Alpha11          NA     1   4
> 7:  sub1      Alpha11          NA     1   4
> 8:  sub1      Alpha11          NA     1   4
> 9:  sub1      Alpha11           3     0  NA
> 10: sub1      Alpha11           3     0  NA
> 11: sub1      Alpha11           3     0  NA
> 12: sub1      Alpha11           3     0  NA
> 13: sub1      Alpha11           3     0  NA
> 14: sub1      Alpha11          NA     2   5
> 15: sub1      Alpha11          NA     2   5
> 16: sub1      Alpha11          NA     2   5
> 17: sub1      Alpha11          NA     2   5
> 18: sub1      Alpha11          NA     2   5
> 19: sub1      Alpha12           1     0  NA
> 20: sub1      Alpha12          NA     1   2
> 21: sub1      Alpha12          NA     1   2
> 22: sub1      Alpha12           2     0  NA
> 23: sub1      Alpha12          NA     2   1
> 24: sub2      Alpha11          NA     1   4
> 25: sub2      Alpha11          NA     1   4
> 26: sub2      Alpha11          NA     1   4
> 27: sub2      Alpha11          NA     1   4
> 28: sub2      Alpha11           2     0  NA
> 29: sub2      Alpha11           2     0  NA
>     Name StimulusName FixationSeq count dur
> ```

---

If desired, change `count == 0` to `NA`:

```
df[count == 0, count := NA]
```

I would not change it to 'blank' (`""`), as shown in the question, because this would coerce the column to `character` and render the numbers useless for further analyses.

---

The `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 0L) & x) * x` part step by step:

```
v <- c(1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA)
x <- is.na(v)
x
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

diff(x)
# [1]  0  1  0 -1  1  0  0

diff(x) != 0L
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

c(TRUE, diff(x) != 0L) & x
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 0L) & x)
# [1] 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2

cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 0L) & x) * x
# [1] 0 0 1 1 0 2 2 2
```

The rest is hopefully rather straightforward.

Comment: Hi @Henrik, I've gotten side tracked finishing off a different bit of coding the last couple of days. Once Ive wrapped that up I'll test your solution on my full dataset and will report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

code:

```
library(data.table)
fun1 <- function(x) {
    na.ind = is.na(x$FixationSeq)
    na.vals= rleidv(rleidv(na.ind)[na.ind])
    x$SaccadeCount = NA
    x$SaccadeCount[na.ind] = na.vals

    na.rle = rle(na.vals)
    x$SaccadeDuration = NA
    x$SaccadeDuration[na.ind] = rep(na.rle$lengths, na.rle$lengths)

    return(x)
    }

setDT(df)[, fun1(.SD) ,by = .(Name, StimulusName)]
```

---

You can use `fun1` in a dplyr fashion:

```
ans<-
df %>% group_by(Name, StimulusName) %>% dplyr::do(.data = ., fun1(.))
```

---

result:

```
 #   Name StimulusName FixationSeq SaccadeCount SaccadeDuration
 #1: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
 #2: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
 #3: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
 #4: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
 #5: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
 #6: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
 #7: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
 #8: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
 #9: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#10: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#11: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#12: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#13: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#14: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#15: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#16: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#17: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#18: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#19: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#20: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#21: sub1      Alpha11           2           NA              NA
#22: sub1      Alpha11          NA            1               5
#23: sub1      Alpha11          NA            1               5
#24: sub1      Alpha11          NA            1               5
#25: sub1      Alpha11          NA            1               5
#26: sub1      Alpha11          NA            1               5
#27: sub1       Alpha1           9           NA              NA
#28: sub1       Alpha1           9           NA              NA
#29: sub1       Alpha1           9           NA              NA
#30: sub1       Alpha1           9           NA              NA
#31: sub1       Alpha1           9           NA              NA
#32: sub1       Alpha1           9           NA              NA
#33: sub1       Alpha1           9           NA              NA
#    Name StimulusName FixationSeq SaccadeCount SaccadeDuration
```

---

- My approach uses a predefined function `fun1` that does the job for each group.
- The groups seem to be defined my `Name` and `StimulusName`
- I use very important functions that you should learn about `?rle`, `?rleidv`
- I prepopulate the new column with all `NA`-values, then I add the new values where needed.

Comment: This solution appears to work well. I'll double check on the full dataset in the morning and get back to you. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Maybe there is an easier way, though. The first **mutate** indicates the start of an *NA* segment. The **group_by** and the second **mutate** count the *NA*s for each segment.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(SaccadeCount = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(FixationSeq) & 
              !is.na(lag(FixationSeq)), 1,0)) * is.na(FixationSeq)) %>%
    group_by(SaccadeCount) %>%
    mutate(SaccadeDuration = n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(SaccadeDuration = SaccadeDuration * is.na(FixationSeq))
```

Comment: cool, this solution seems to work. I would replace the `0` with `NA`, since in the desired outcome you have "nothing" there, what normally indicated `NA`.

Comment: Hi @FloSchmo, I've tried this with my full dataset and it's a little buggy. I've added a `group_by(Name, StimulusName)` before the first `mutate` and added `group_by(SaccadeCount, Name, StimulusName, FixationSeq)` before the second `mutate` which almost works perfectly. The only remaining issue is that some of the `SaccadeCount` values begin with `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: If you group by Name and StimulusName you might get problems if a chunk of NAs is split up between different StimulusNames or Names. I can unfortunately not see why there should be chunks starting with 0. Maybe you can provide a reproducible example dataframe?

Comment: @FloSchmo Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the original question to reflect this type of scenario. Using my modified version of your code as detailed above it replicates the starting at 0 issue.